# Ordering by nested json objects with lodash

Tags: json, lodash

I have a json file that is requested from a server so i can't modify how is sent, i want to order those objects by a property that is really nested (for example the average property that is located in localidades)

> estados(array of objects)
>
> > id (property)
> >
> > name (property)
> >
> > localidades (array of objects)
> >
> > > id (property)
> > >
> > > name (property)
> > >
> > > type1 (object)
> > >
> > > > average (property)
> > >
> > > type2 (object) etc..

i only know how to order a simple array of objects in lodash, but not this type of complex object, any hints/suggestions?

here is a json sample :
http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=9cd4c3af94f14b1cca2d35226794ea78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data does not have an 'average' or even 'avg' field. [Here is an example](http://jsbin.com/nededa/6/edit?js,console,output), based on averaging the 'promedio' field for each estado.

What I did is use the _.sortBy with a more advanced predicate.